# Puppeteer: Some of the images are not loading properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, puppeteer

I am trying to parse a webpage everything is working fine but some of the images are getting broken.

[image]

i tried everything but got no luck here is my code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 10000 })
  await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 0,
  });

await page.evaluate(() => {
const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img') || []
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].src = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute('src')?.startsWith('https') ?
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute('src')! :
        `https://leza.notion.site${document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute('src')}`
    }
})
```

Here is the actual website which i am trying to parse https://leza.notion.site/Trade-log-721b1ebb4cc74175abb55408b6f2d0c3

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You have a typo...`https://leza.notion.site${document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute('src')}`
    }

You forgot the $ before the ${ }

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound sorry it was a typo while posting question, i have updated it